# How to add another LDAP entry in OPENLDAP using ldapadd

Tags: ldap, openldap

I added an LDAP entry with `ldapadd` and `ldif` file.

Now I have one entry.

[image]

I changed `ldif` file and tried to add a new entry.

```
dn: dc=my-domain,dc=com
objectclass: dcObject
objectclass: organization
o: dsm
dc: MY-DOMAIN

dn: cn=Manager,dc=my-domain,dc=com
objectclass: organizationalRole
cn: Manager

dn: cn=singer,dc=my-domain,dc=com
objectclass: organizationalRole
cn: singer
```

I got :

> ldap_add: Already exists (68)

How can I add another entry in **OPENLDAP**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears you are trying to add these again: (Remove these lines)

```
dn: dc=my-domain,dc=com
objectclass: dcObject
objectclass: organization
o: dsm
dc: MY-DOMAIN

dn: cn=Manager,dc=my-domain,dc=com
objectclass: organizationalRole
cn: Manager
```